# Webpage not working - HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Iv almost finished working on a website. The website is a html5 one page site.

But the problem is that one page of the page isn't working. Its the weblinks section.

Its a drop down box that displays links when a selection is made

I'm not sure why. It uses java script , so that may be the issue. (I'm not good with java script)

Iv provided two links below . The first is the actual website.

The second is just the weblinks section which works on its own.

[Link 1](http://mk18.comoj.com)

[Link 2](http://mk18.comoj.com/WebLinks.html)

Thanks in advance.

Javascript code

```
> $(window).load(function(){
var select = $( '#dropdown' );

function showTab( name ) {
  name = '#' + name;
  $( 'div' ).not( name ).hide();
  $( name ).show();
}

select.change( function() {
  showTab( $( this ).val() );   
});

showTab( select.val() );
});
```

Comment: Firstly, post your code here. Secondly, I went to your web site, clicked a weblink and arrived at an advertiser's site: what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry cannot post the code, there is too much of it. Click the second link , thats how its supposed to be , on the actual website all the links are visable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, your problem is that on the actual website page, all the links are being displayed on page load instead of like in the sample page where they are hidden and displayed only based on selection.

If this is the case assign the `style: display: none;` to all the individual div tags. This will hide the links on page load. You can do this like below:

`<div id="Option" style="display: none;"> <a href="#">Sample</a> </div>`

If you don't want to use inline styles, create a CSS class (say `hidden`) in the following way and assign it to all the Divs that need to be hidden.

```
.hidden{ 
    display: none;
}
```

The JS currently seems to be hiding all DIVs whose ID does not equal the selected item's value. This was making your `mainContent1` also get hidden. Try the code present in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/qg4fE/). It is a mini version of your code.

I have added a CSS class `hidden` to the divisions and in the `showTab` function of the JS instead of

`$('div').not(name).hide();`

use the following line (this will select only DIVs within mainContent1 for hiding).

`$('#mainContent1 > div').not(name).hide();`

Comment: Okay , ill make the changes ad give it a try.

Comment: That almost worked . While the divs are now hidden , the dont show up when a selection is made.  I have posted the java script file used for the weblinks section

Comment: That didnt work. Same problem as before . divs are hidden , but dont show up when selected.

Comment: I did check the link and I edited the uf2 javascrip file to have your code instead of the original.   just look at the code of the actual website.

Comment: Try using `$(document).ready(function () {` in the first line of the JS instead of the current one. Sorry mate, the sample that I have is working, so I am doing and bit of trial and error stuff :(

Comment: nope didnt work , . I think some other code is messing with it because the sample weblinks page works with that code.

Comment: I dont know what this means . Im not good with java script

Comment: Ok. Add `alert(name);` inside the showTab funtion after the first line and check if you get any alert message box.

Comment: Hey , thanks for all your help , but it seems that I have found another solution with different javascript. I will post that .

Comment: Can you try using `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` instead of the first line of the current JS? this one should work hopefully. else you can switch over to the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code that I have found :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"><!--
var lastDiv = "";
function showDiv(divName) {
    // hide last div
    if (lastDiv) {
        document.getElementById(lastDiv).className = "hiddenDiv";
    }
    //if value of the box is not nothing and an object with that name exists, then change the class
    if (divName && document.getElementById(divName)) {
        document.getElementById(divName).className = "visibleDiv";
        lastDiv = divName;
    }
}
//-->
</script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"><!--
.hiddenDiv {
    display: none;
    }
.visibleDiv {
    display: block;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    }

--></style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <form id="FormName" action="blah.php" method="get" name="FormName">
            <select name="selectName" size="1" onchange="showDiv(this.value);">
                <option value="">Choose One...</option>
                <option value="one">first</option>
                <option value="two">second</option>
                <option value="three">third</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <p id="one" class="hiddenDiv">This is paragraph 1.</p>
        <p id="two" class="hiddenDiv">This is paragraph 2.</p>
        <p id="three" class="hiddenDiv">This is paragraph 3.</p>        
    </body>

</html>
```